# Postgres idle connections: CannotAcquireResourceException

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have a web application in Java/ Wicket using Hibernate 4.1.1 and Spring 3.1.1 and Postgres 9.2. I also use spring transaction api and c3p0 connection pool.

My Problem is that the available connections are not released and after executing some select statements caused by the gui I get the following Exception

> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A
>   ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or
>   source. Executing `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` shows that there
>   are many idle queries like this : `SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, n.nspname
>   AS TABLE_SCHEM, c.relname AS TABLE_NAME,  CASE n.nspname ~ '^pg_' OR
>   n.nspname = 'information_schema'  WHEN true THEN CASE  WHEN n.nspname
>   = 'pg_catalog' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema' THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TABLE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'SYSTEM VIEW'   WHEN 'i'
>   THEN 'SYSTEM INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_toast'
>   THEN CASE c.relkind   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST TABLE'   WHEN 'i'
>   THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST INDEX'   ELSE NULL   END  ELSE CASE c.relkind
>
>   WHEN 'r' THEN 'TEMPORARY TABLE'   WHEN 'i' THEN 'TEMPORARY INDEX'
>
>   WHEN 'S' THEN 'TEMPORARY SEQUENCE'   WHEN 'v' THEN 'TEMPORARY VIEW'
>
>   ELSE NULL   END  END  WHEN false THEN CASE c.relkind  WHEN 'r' THEN
>   'TABLE'  WHEN 'i' THEN 'INDEX'  WHEN 'S' THEN 'SEQUENCE'  WHEN 'v'
>   THEN 'VIEW'  WHEN 'c' THEN 'TYPE'  ELSE NULL  END  ELSE NULL  END  AS
>   TABLE_TYPE, d.description AS REMARKS  FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n,
>   pg_catalog.pg_class c  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON (c.oid
>   = d.objoid AND d.ob`

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                    destroy-method="close">
           <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
           <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase"/>
           <property name="user" value="myuser"/>
           <property name="password" value="mypassword"/>

           <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->
           <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3"/>
           <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
           <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30"/>
           <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="600"/>
           <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0"/>
           <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
           <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="0"/>
           <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
           <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
           <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000"/>
           <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
           <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="14400"/>
           <property name="forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions" value="false"/>
           <property name="numHelperThreads" value="20"/>
           <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false"/>
           <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
           <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="0"/>
           <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="false"/>
           <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="0"/>
           <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
           <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="0"/>
           <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="0"/>
           <property name="usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies" value="false"/>
      </bean>

    <bean id="exampleDao"
        class="com.mycompany.persistence.hibernate.daoimpl.ExampleDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.model.Example</value>
        </list>
      </property>

      <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxSize">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">30</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT * FROM dual</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Transaction Management -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Is the configuration correct?

My Classes to retrieve the data from the database are like this:

```
@Repository
public class ExampleDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements ExampleDao {
...
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Example> findExampleByCompanyAndType(Company company,
            int type) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Example.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("company.companyId",
                        company.getCompanyId()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("type", type)).list();

    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't implement 'dual' so you may have intended something like SELECT 1 there, for the test query. I don't know if that will fix your problems but it should help the container manage itself better.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but this didn't solve the problem. It changed the idle queries to `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE` and "SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL``

Comment: I would continue by enabling:
           <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false"/>
           <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
and
           <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="false"/>

Comment: I might also try changing to a different connection pooler at this point. I have had good luck with Apache dbcp as well as Tomcat's new built-in pooler. Both can be configured in the container and wired into your app via JNDI.